# Redis taking up all server memory. What to do?

Tags: redis

I have a Redis server running version 2.4.5 and with a dump.rdb of 11GB loaded into memory.
It is running on EC2 on a high memory 4x extra large instance (70GB total memory). 
However, turns out Redis is already taking up 50GB of memory and is just growing more and more. My dataset is still gonna grow larger, probably to around 20GB, so clearly 70GB memory wont be enough. Do you guys have any ideas on how to overcome this limitation or how to make Redis eat less memory?

I've tried redis 32bit but it dies trying to load the data set into memory at startup.

Have also tried max-memory in the past but got weird results. Haven't tried virtual memory since I read it is/was gonna be deprecated.

Comment: You might have more luck with your question if you try posting to http://serverfault.com

Comment: good point. maybe I should move it there

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/345186/redis-taking-up-all-server-memory-what-to-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the discussion in the comments, I think this problem can be solved with programming, not server configuration

Systems like redis work well sharded. Once you have your scheme set up, you can get it to scale pretty easily. It does take some work to get it set up though in the client code.

For example...

You could shard it across 4x instances using a modulo/hash scheme.

Basically, if `md5sum(key) % 4 == 0`, it goes to server 0; if `md5sum(key) % 4 == 1`, it goes to server 1, etc.

You'll have to add some logic into your client to make sure it accesses the right one. When you get a record, figure out which server it is suppose to be at, then query that one. If you have to set a record, figure out which server it is suppose to be at, then set it in that one.

The nice thing about this is that it doesn't affect your performance.

Comment: You should take a look at [consistent hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing). It has more advantages than basic modulo hashing.

Comment: donald,sorry for late comment.how to shard it to ensure it is well load balaced after sharding?I maintain visited urls in redis,and want to accept the sharding policy,but I haven't figured out which sharding policy is good.In your case,how the memory will be used by the 4 instances,they have the same amount memory or just use how much data they maintain.thx